Laravel Passport: TypeError: Argument #2 ($guard) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
I'm encountering an error when using Laravel Passport with Laravel version 10.48.22 and Laravel Passport version 12.3.0.
Steps to reproduce:

I moved the predefined application routes to a separate file api.php following the Laravel documentation.

I set the guard in the config/passport.php file to 'api'.


Error Message:
TypeError: Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizationController::__construct(): Argument #2 ($guard) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard, Laravel\Passport\Guards\TokenGuard given in file C:\PHP\rest-api-backend\vendor\laravel\passport\src\Http\Controllers\AuthorizationController.php on line 52   


I verified that the api guard is defined correctly in config/auth.php.

I reviewed the Laravel Passport documentation for any additional configuration needed for the api guard.

I searched Stack Overflow for similar issues but couldn't find a solution.


Possible Causes:

There might be a mismatch between the expected guard type by AuthorizationController and the provided TokenGuard.

There might be a configuration issue requiring additional steps to enable the api guard with Laravel Passport.


What I Need Help With:

Understanding why AuthorizationController expects a StatefulGuard instead of the provided TokenGuard.

Finding a way to resolve the type mismatch and make the api guard work with Laravel Passport.


Additional Information:

Relevant code snippets:

config/passport.php (guard configuration)

config/auth.php (API guard definition)

api.php (relevant route definitions)



I've commented out the pre-defined Laravel Passport routes in api.php.



I'm using Laravel 11.3 and Passport 12.3. I have the same issue.
Digging into the documentation, I found that if you look at Passport's route definitions (https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/11.x/routes/web.php), you will see that it defines the authorization route with the web guard, where auth would be a StatefulGuard.
When I changed the guard in my passport config to web, the error went away as it should, getting its StatefulGuard, but it tried to redirect to a Laravel GET login named route (laravelwhatever.test/login) instead of the redirect I provided.

I figured this out yesterday. For the PKCE implementation, you need to leave web set as the guard in the passport config.
The goal is for the login and registration to occur on views from the server. Then, it will prompt the user for authorized access to your client application (it does this by the name you chose when creating your client).
If you think of other OAuth flows, you are often taken to another URL to log in and be redirected to the application. That's what the PCKE implementation is.
Here is what I did for my Login/Register.
Note: I installed Inertia on my Laravel instance because I haven't used Blade in some time and didn't feel like returning. I also wanted to be consistent with my Next app.
public function login(): Response
{
    return Inertia::render('Auth/Login');
}

public function authenticate(WebLoginRequest $request)
{
    if (!auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'), $request->remember)) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => trans('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }

    return redirect()->intended();
}


    public function register(): Response
{
    return Inertia::render('Auth/Register');
}

public function store(WebRegisterRequest $request)
{
    User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    ]);

    return redirect('login');
}

I also have an implementation for PKCE that would let users log in to the client, so I'll probably do a blog post soon with coverage of all of it.
